# COM Exception in Application

Tags: comexception, interopservices

I'm trying to upgrade an internal application, the infrastructure will be moving from 2008 to windows server 2012. The application builds presentations from model templates.

I keep getting the attached COM Exception which looks to be associated with Interops, has anyone come across something similar.

PowerPages (Office 14.0)

Document: Model.ppt

Command: *{SET PrevPeriodEnd user.PreviousPeriodEnd(PGFromDate)}*

Error:

~~ Call Stack Pages 6.9.1  (Build 021)~~

Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Stack Trace:

at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.Run(String MacroName, Object& varg1, Object& varg2, Object& varg3, Object& varg4, Object& varg5, Object& varg6, Object& varg7, Object& varg8, Object& varg9, Object& varg10, Object& varg11, Object& varg12, Object& varg13, Object& varg14, Object& varg15, Object& varg16, Object& varg17, Object& varg18, Object& varg19, Object& varg20, Object& varg21, Object& varg22, Object& varg23, Object& varg24, Object& varg25, Object& varg26, Object& varg27, Object& varg28, Object& varg29, Object& varg30)

at Pages.PowerPages.Evaluate.DoEvaluate(Collection cExpression)

at Pages.PowerPages.Evaluate.Eval(String sExpression)

at Pages.PowerPages.Commands.HandleSet(String& sStr, Shape& oShape, TextRange& oRange)

at Pages.PowerPages.ProcessFile.ProcessShape(Presentation& oPresentation, Shape& shp, String& sOpenStr, String& sCloseStr, Boolean& bExit, Int32& nSlideID, Int32& nSlidesToReset, Boolean& bAgenda)

at Pages.PowerPages.ProcessFile.ProcessPresentation(Presentation& oPresentation, String& sOpenStr, String& sCloseStr, Boolean& BMaster, Boolean& bAgenda)

at Pages.PowerPages.modAmain.GenerateModel(String[]& aSelectedComponent, Boolean& bNormal)

at Pages.PowerPages.modAmain.Generate2(Boolean bJobRun)

at Pages.PowerPages.ComPowerPoint.Generate(String sThreadID, Int32 nJobID, String sPortcode, String sManager, String sBusinessUnit, Int32 nJobAccountStatusID, Object oBatch, String sOutputFolder, Application oPowerPointApp)

~~~~ Additional Information ~~~~

Exception type: COMException

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Computer Data:

Operating System Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Version: 6.2.9200.0

Platform: Win32NT

Physical Memory - Total: 4294430720, Available: 2845433856

Virtual Memory - Total: 2147352576, Available: 1652203520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two (obvious) possibilities:

Is word installed? Looks like whatever is calling powerpoint is also calling word.

Is your app running as a 32 bit app? 2008 can be run as a 32 bit OS but 2012R2 is 64 bit and you may need to mark everything as 32 bit. (I think you can use CorFlag.exe to force this)

Comment: Hi, Yes full office is installed and the file is available in the correct place. I believe everything is running as 64bit

Comment: I'd be tempted to try everything as 32 bit to be honest.

Comment: Apologies, everything is 32bit.

Comment: Guessing a bit more, looks like a macro is being run and that's the actual failure (so word is probably starting). Have you tried talking to ss&c tech (assuming I've googled the right product)?

Comment: Thanks, I think I've resolved, the macro called template was in an out of date version of office (.dot and required .dotm.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I think I've resolved, the macro called template was in an out of date version of office (.dot and required .dotm.)